# Why does my cassandra database not return existing data?

Tags: python, cassandra

I use a python driver to query the data. The data exists in the database but does not return it to the python script.

This is a sample query:

```
SELECT article, comments, likes, reads, shares FROM axes WHERE article = '6238336083283017986' AND at >= '2016-01-11 21:28:58'
```

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: you will have to show your table structure. By the kind of query I fill that you should add ALLOW FILTERING at the end but it has very high performance penalty and is anti-pattern

Comment: Which consistency level is used by your select query? If you are using CL ONE your query could return nothing. You should provide more info - cluster topology, replication factor etc.

Comment: Have you logged into you server and used cqlsh or used DevCenter to verify that the query you have listed above works exactly as typed?